# Supply voltage in a current mirror necessary?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current-mirror

Consider the current mirror below (circuit taken from [[Razavi]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072524936)). I wonder about the \$ V_{DD} \$ in the circuit. No matter if its there or not, \$ V_{GS} \$ of M1 stays the same and therefore also \$ I_D \$ of M2, since the current charges up parasitic capacitances of M1 and causes a voltage across it. This I also verified by simulation, see the plot below (\net01 and \net02 are the \$ V_{GS} \$ of M1 with \$ V_{DD} \$ and without). Is there any reason why \$ V_{DD} \$ is connected there?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQxb7c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

EDIT:
I simulated the circuit until 100V, \$ V_{GS} \$ stays the same. Here is the circuit:
[image]

Comment: Try this in the simulator and see if it makes any difference if V_DD is 0 V, 5 V or 1234.567 V. As long as I1 is ideal it.....

Comment: If I simulate until 100V \$ V_{DD} \$ I see no difference, see my EDIT.

Comment: And **why** is that. Yes I know the answer, I want **you** to think about it and say the answer.

Comment: @FakeMoustache As long as I1 is ideal it has infinite impedance and Vdd drops entirely over I1?

Comment: I1 does have an infinite impedance but impedance is a small signal parameter. It does not affect the DC solution of this circuit. The real answer is that I1 is an **ideal current source** so **whatever** you do on either side of it (either node) it will maintain the DC current is supposed to, no matter what. So the  node to which the transistor is connected does not even "see" what happens on the other node. An ideal current source simply enforces a certain current out of (node where the arrow is pointing to) or into (the other node) that node.

Answer (score 4):

If I1 is a current 'source' then no, you wouldn't need the voltage source.  But typically a current source is implemented using a voltage source and current regulation, so when I look at that drawing I assume I1 just regulates the current from the voltage source V_DD (even though the symbol is that of a current source).